# Kibana API Action and connector APIs returning 404

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-7

I'm trying to use the actions and connector endpoints of the kibana api and its giving me 404, but things to do with listing spaces work fine

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.x/actions-and-connectors-api.html

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://kibana.<acme>.com/api/actions/connector_types' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <redacted>'
```

> {
> "statusCode": 404,
> "error": "Not Found",
> "message": "Not Found" }

Comment: i'm finding the same for POST `/api/actions/connector/` on an 8.2.0 cluster. my issue was i had a trailing slash